# how to get tags name that have data with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, integration

I have XML payload that looks like

```
<payload>
<field1>data1</field1> 
<field2>data2</field2>
<field3>data3</field3>
<field4></field4>
</payload>
```

I want the function to get name of tags that contains data and convert it to the following result

```
result : field1,field2,field3
```

is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two templates in an XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  result: <xsl:apply-templates select="payload/*[normalize-space(.)]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select='name()' />
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

> result: field1,field2,field3

Comment: Then change `payload/*[normalize-space(.)]` to `payload/*[not(normalize-space())]`.

Comment: Thanks it worked , but how to handle nested xml tags

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:value-of select="/payload/*[normalize-space()]" separator=", "/>` should do in XSLT 2 or 3.